# what things may I need to start withdrawal of bitcoins

Tags: blockchain, wallet, address, withdrawal

I'm new on bitcoins business the problem now is to withdraw my bitcoins to my account or exchange it to normal cash.

Comment: Why exactly is this a problem?  There are MANY services that will trade cash for bitcoin. A simple web-search will find them.  What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Transfer them to coinbase.com or gemini.com then sell them. Then add your bank account and withdraw the money you just sold your bitcoin's for.